2012 Mazda 6 stereo issues
I replaced the stereo a few weeks ago and everything was fine and worked perfect.  Two days ago the radio would not come when I got in the car in the morning to go to work.  After I left work I went to my car and saw that my stereo was on and playing even though the car was not started and the keys were not in the ignition.  Once I started the car the radio turned off and would not come back on.  Arrived home and turned car off and radio did not come back on.  Then today radio has not been on but I went out to my car during the day and the radio was back on but once again when I started the car the radio shut off.  Not sure what my issue is.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Your description suggests that there may be an issue with the ignition switch. If you have a big load of keys attached to your ignition key, that tends to wear out the switch faster. (It can wear out without the weight of extra keys too.)
Try inserting the ignition key and slowly forcing it every which way: inward, outward, left, right and up-down. Then try rotating the key just enough so it moves slightly but does not turn on the ignition or start the car, followed by forcing in all directions. Do the same thing with slight rotation in the other direction (toward ACC if your car has that position) and force in all directions.
If you find that some combination of rotation and force turns the radio on without the ignition being on or the car running, then it's confirmed that you have a bad ignition switch.
You may also have a bad ignition switch if you can't get it to misbehave this way, but best to try this first.
